# Reflexil deobfustication error

Tags: mono, reflector, deobfuscation, reflexil

I'm trying to modify a .net application and I'm new to this.  First step is attempting to deobfuscate the code using reflexil and I get the following error:

*Reflexil is unable to clean this assembly: Member 'System.RuntimeTypeHandle "bunch of obfustatcated jibberish"(System.Int32)' is declared in another module and needs to be imported*

The application comes with a bunch of dll's that it certainly uses, so I assume the declaration is in one of those files.  How do I import this module?

In case it's helpful, reflexil says it was obfuscated with .NET Reactor 4.1

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try de4not to deobfuscate and it worked without this issue.